# MariaDB trigger loop

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

i'm creating a database for school. This is the problem:
i got a table with attributes A,B and C (where C=(A/(A+B))*100). On the update of attributes A or B i need to update C. 
I tried different things but the trigger keeps going into loop bacause when i update A or B the trigger updates C so it keeps going.
This code doesn't work(sintax error):

```
Create trigger nametrigger
after update of (A or B) on tablename
```

But i somehow need to specify that the trigger has to activate on the update of A or B and not C.

Comment: Yet another reason to keep your code in the client.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you don't need a trigger, you need `C` to be a [computed column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) (a.k.a. virtual column).

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t (
  a INT, 
  b INT, 
  c INT AS ((a/(a+b))*100) PERSISTENT
);

MariaDB [test]> insert into t (a,b) values (1,1);
MariaDB [test]> insert into t (a,b) values (2,2);

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |   50 |
|    2 |    2 |   50 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> update t set b = b*2;

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |   33 |
|    2 |    4 |   33 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is just an example, not a solution. You need to read about computed columns to decide how exactly it needs to be configured.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can do the same even if A and B are attributes in another table?

Comment: No, you can't, as you could find out from the first paragraph of the "Virtual (Computed) Columns" page by the link provided in the question. But as the answer specifically points out, it addresses the situation _as you describe it_, and you were explicitly saying that all columns belong to the same table: " i got a table with attributes A,B and C..."